# Neo4j Default Database Location (Windows)

Tags: neo4j

With the Neo4j 2.0.0 Community edition, is there a way to change the default database location?

Seems like every time I start the program it points back to the default location (in the user's documents directory).

I tried editing the neo4j-server.properties file and adding a line to specify the desired directory there, but this didn't seem to work:

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=C:\MyGraphDatabaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting Neo4j 2.0 Community edition on Windows you will see a dialog UI with a data folder location that you can browse to. To change your data location, browse to a different folder and then click the start button.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm looking for is a way to persist that selection, so that the next time that I open the program I don't have to navigate to the directory again.

Comment: What is your scenario? It may make more sense for you to not use the Windows installer if you are looking to configure Neo4j for a production scenario. For example, you can download the zip distribution of Neo4j 2.0 community and modify the configuration to point to the desired data directory. http://download.neo4j.org/artifact?edition=community&version=2.0.0&distribution=zip

Comment: I'm just starting out using Neo4j.  I wanted to do a small project to try to learn more about graph databases and play around with them.

Comment: Having to navigate to the directory every time I started Neo4j was getting annoying, so I was hoping there was a better way (e.g. configuration setting, command line argument), but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Thanks, right now there is not a way to do this for the installer version on Windows. It looks like the code automatically defaults to a path variable for the user's document directory and appends default.graphdb which was created during the installation. I will provide feedback to the product team to fix this in the next release. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The plan is to both allow the command line invocation to specify a directory as an argument; and also improve the GUI to include a "recent databases" dropdown which would default to the most recent.

Comment: Kenny, Saw that you were online. How do you do the same in Ubuntu/Linux? I searched everywhere on SO, everything is regarding Windows itself. :(

Comment: This is quite easy thankfully. The neo4j.properties config file is located at /path/to/neo4j/conf/neo4j.properties and there is a property in that file to your desired database location. See here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html

Your config files would be located at /etc/neo4j/config/neo4j.properties if you installed with debian package.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the default location seems to be limitation of the community edition. What you can do is a "[junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)" using the [mklink](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) command:

```
mklink /j C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb D:\Data\Neo4j\default.graphdb
```

That way you don't need to change the path of the database. The default path will point to the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing you can get to is to add a shortcut (to your app's neo4j database) in the default neo4j database folder (or in the parent folder),

I.E.:
In C:\Users\YOURUSER\Documents\Neo4j create a Windows Shortcut (browse to the folder in windows explorer, right click-> create shortcut), --> Create the shortcut to your app's neo4j db location.

Then when you open Neo4j's Window gui, you can go to browse -> click your shortcut and be directly into the folder you want.

It's far from a perfect solution, but it saves a lot of clicking!

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you create a new folder and the you choose it when you want to start your server